# Get next week in second textbox

Tags: asp.net, date

I have 2 textboxes.

I want that when I pick date in first textbox using datepicker then second TextBox automatically show next week date.

How can I do this ?

Here is my code-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx):

```
txtToDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(txtDateFrom.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddDays(7).ToString("dd.MM.yy");
```

You can use this code in `txtDateFrom` leave event or value change event

Comment: It is not working when I leave. It is working when i click button. I have added more code to my question. Please check it.

Comment: @12345 Check `IsPostBack` property of `txtFromDate` it must be true to request server side code.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).AddDays(7.0).ToString();
```

You need to make correct datetime format like (MM/dd/yyyy) of textbox before convert. If you use dd/MM/yyyy format then check below code.

```
string[] date1 = TextBox1.Value.Split('/');
string FinalDate1 = date1[1] + "/" + date1[0] + "/" + date1[2];
TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(FinalDate1).AddDays(7.0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Answer (score 0):

Add 7 days to the first date value.

```
        DateTime date1 = System.DateTime.Now;
        DateTime date2 = date1.AddDays(7);
```